# Change the template of multiple multisite pages at the same time

Tags: theme-development, multisite, templates

I have a multisite network with hundreds of individual location-based sites that use the same theme and display the same type of content.

Occasionally I will need to create or change the template of a page for one site and do so by logging in and out of each subsite to repeat this change across the network.

Is there a better way to do this through the shared theme? Ideally, I would like to learn how to define a set of rules: if page name is equal to "Example", always use the `example.php` template file and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If these pages are using the default `page.php` template, just create a file called `page-{slug}.php`. So for example, if each subsite has a page with a slug of 'my-cool-page' you'll create a template file called `page-my-cool-page.php`, upload it to the active theme, and all of the pages with that slug will automatically use that template. (If it's not a custom-coded theme, be sure to use a [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) so your changes won't be lost.)

If the pages are already using a custom template - i.e. you selected `tpl-my-cool-template.php` from the template dropdown in the editor - that will override `page-my-cool-page.php' and you will have to update them one by one. But it does not sound like that is the case.

Comment: Unfortunately yes, they are using custom templates. It seems like I should be able to copy template.php to page-template.php instead?

Comment: No, if they're using custom templates that you picked from a dropdown list, that will override files like page-{slug}.php. Anytime you pick from the dropdown list it will be a manual process to change it in the future.